# better jquery scroll to plugin than scrollTo?

Tags: jquery

ScrollTo isn't the smoothest animation i've seen and i also notice that it hasn't been updated for a while..

are there any new similar plugins that out perform scrollTo or is it still top of its game?

Comment: What are you looking to scroll? Overflow divs, to the top of the page, other?

Comment: yep an overflow div, say 400px high with a vertical scroll

Answer (score 2):

You should read the [documentation](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html), it has information on how you can configure it. There are a lot of options, you can get it to behave the way you like.

[ScrollTo plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any other plugins as robust as this though It would be nice to know if there was anything better. ScrollTo along with serialScroll have been very handy in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I searched long and hard and couldn't find any, as I needed one now I ended up creating my own.

In terms of smoothing out the animation, if you have an element inside a scrollable area. It will scroll the body to the scrollable area, and then scroll to the item within the scrollable area. This is quite different than Ariel's functionality which will just perform the latter scroll above.

> http://www.balupton.com/projects/jquery-scrollto
>
> jQuery ScrollTo (balupton edition) is a great and
>   reliable way to scroll to any element
>   on your page. It brings such features
>   as:
>
> - Extremely simple to use: just call $('#element).ScrollTo() and your user
>     will be smoothly scrolled to that
>     element!
> - Only 1KB in size! Making it the smallest ScrollTo plugin and won't
>     slow you down.
> - Supports all the elements you can throw at it! Even those ones in modals
>     and scrollable areas! So you can now
>     feel at ease knowing your user will
>     always be scrolled to that correct
>     place which you intended.
> - It's even easy customise and work with! You can specify such options as
>     duration, easing, and callback on your
>     ScrollTo call.

Comment: so this is a different scrollTo plugin, or the same?

Comment: Different made by someone else.